# Question about the notation $\{x \in \mathbb{Z}: p(x)\}$

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

A book I'm currently working through has the following exercise.

$1.5$ Write each of the following sets in the form $\{x \in \mathbb{Z} : p(x)\}$, where $p(x)$ is a property concerning $x$.

$$(a)\ A = \{-1, -2, -3,...\}\\
(b)\ B = \{-3, -2, ..., 3\}\\
(c)\ C = \{-2, -1, 1, 2\}
$$

I'm not exactly sure what the $p(x)$ is asserting here, do they want me to come up with a transformation for each $x$ by means of some function?

The only way I can even conceive of answering these would be something like the following

$(a)\ A = \{x\in \mathbb{Z}: x< 0\}$
But this isn't some transformation $p(x)$. I don't know a function that is not piecewise who will take some $x$ and transform it to $-x$ but leaves $x$ positive if it's positive?

$(b)\ B = \{x\in \mathbb{Z} : |x|\leq3\}$

$(c)\ C = \{x\in \mathbb{Z} : 0 \lt|x|\leq2\}$

Again neither of my solutions $(c)$ or $(b)$ are of the form $p(x)$ I'm just giving some hard rules on what x has to be here. If anyone has any ideas on how I can approach these differently I would appreciate it.
Regrettably, my book comes with exactly zero solutions.

Comment: This looks fine; you can interpret $p(x)$ as a statement imposing a restriction on $x$. It is not a transformation.

Comment: I have no idea where you might be coming from or who might be grading your work but those definitely look like properties to me. Often properties are just symbolic statements involving a variable that might be very complicated (and not for example just functions of one variable).

Comment: I'm assuming you mean $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @leslietownes I have no one grading my work, unfortunately. I'm just doing this because I want to learn this stuff. I've picked up a few books on analysis, set theory, and linear algebra which I've been working through back and forth. When I get stuck in one. I retreat to another until I can come back and understand a concept.

Comment: @MichaelWalker as Theophile noted properties of $x$ are generally just sentences in a symbolic language that involve $x$, which your descriptions are. They don't have to do more than that and extremely often aren't more than that. You know what you're doing.

Comment: Alright, great thank you Théophile and leslietownes.

Comment: @Théophile If you could turn your comment into a solution so I can close this it would be great.

Comment: @MichaelWalker Sure thing; I added a bit of additional explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your work looks fine; you can interpret $p(x)$ as a statement imposing a restriction on $x$. It is not a transformation.

It's fine even to use words:
$$A = \{x \in \Bbb Z : x < 0\}\\
A' = \{x \in \Bbb Z : x \textrm{ is negative}\}$$

The sets $A$ and $A'$ are exactly the same; it's just that one is more compact to write. (You won't often see "$x$ is negative" written out like that; a more common example would be something like "$x$ is a prime number".)

Comment: Great, thank you for the explanation.

Comment: I'd add that a lot of math can be expressed as converting between (1) an description of a set in a form that (as here) provides an explicit test for membership, but may not give guidance on how to generate its elements, and (2) a description that provides a way of generating elements of the set, but might not shed light on general properties of elements of the set. The quadratic formula goes one way with $\{x \in \mathbb{R}: ax^2 + bx + c = 0\}$. A description of $\{\sum_{k=a}^b k : a, b \in \mathbb{N}, a < b\}$ that sheds light on the which numbers actually take this form would go the other.

Comment: @leslietownes Yes, that's very insightful.